# Extract longitude latitude and radius from POSTGIS column

Tags: postgis, geometry, circle

I have entered the circle in the Geometry type column (name=shape) in my POSTGIS as following:

```
ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint($longitude, $latitude)::geography, $radius)::geometry
```

Then I extracted the centre using:

```
ST_astext(ST_centroid(shape))
```

But it gave me a little different value than that of I entered previously.So Can anybody help me find my mistake.Also I need to extract the radius from above table.

Comment: How different value? About radius you can use st_maxdistanse and divide by 2 but it will not give you an exact value either. That is because the buffer is just an appriximation of a circle built of a limited number of points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that code works you are creating a point on a sphere ( `::geography` ) the buffering by a radius and requesting it as a shape on a plane ( `::geometry` )

Then `st_astext` converts to wkt, yet more info (inc, any SRID) is returned via the PostGIS `ST_AsEWKT` calls.

So you have some reading to do:  Doc on `geography` and `geometry`  http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography

Also please confirm that this is code you are using, also if this works it's really strange:

> ($longitude, $latitude)::geography

As `ST_MakePoint` doesn't take a `geography` type, only `lat`, `lon`, and `z`, `m`.
[ST_MakePoint](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_MakePoint.html)

And that's likely to be your problem.

If possible try and perform those commands using `pgsql` or `pgAdmin` and then when you know what you are doing recreate them in your php.